# addEventListener to all buttons using forEach

Tags: javascript, button, foreach, addeventlistener

I am trying to `addEventListener` to all of my buttons. This is my first time using `addEventListener` and it is not running the `usergetNumber` function which should display a random number when any button is clicked.

```
const btns = document.querySelectorAll(".button");

btns.forEach(function(i) {
    i.addEventListener('click', usergetNumber(){
    });

function usergetNumber(){
    const userRanNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)
    userscore_div.innerHTML = "You have " + userRanNum + " points";
    computergetNumber();

function computergetNumber(){
    const compRanNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)
    computerscore_div.innerHTML = "You have " + compRanNum + " points";
}

What am I doing wrong?
```

Comment: `....addEventListener('click', usergetNumber );`

Comment: There are quite a few problems with this code.  Missing closures, variables that don't exist...etc  Check it out in jsfiddle, and post the reviewed / revised code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From top to bottom.

1. There's already a function `usergetNumber() { ... }` declaration in `addEventListener()`. It's a function declaration not a callback here. Ref: [Event Listener Callbacks](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#the_event_listener_callback).
2. The closing bracket on `usergetNumber() { ...` is missing so therefore it isn't declared.

*Here's a basic example. You can also just `return` and not `console.log`. Here, I'm just trying to duplicate the logic.*

```
const btn = document.querySelectorAll('button');
    
function getRandomNum() {
  let randomNum = Math.random();
  console.log(randomNum);
} 

btn.forEach(function(button) {
  button.addEventListener('click', getRandomNum);
});
```